# How to run second process after finish first process

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, task, filestream

I am generating new text file on every 5 seconds and write records in it. I have generate different method for both processes. So first of all it creates a file and process start for write data in it and again if create file method access again after 5 second then record not write completely in prior file. So how can I make it complete and after that create new file?

I am applying below code for implementation:

```
const string filePath = @"D:\TestSymbolsData.txt";
public static void ReadAndWriteInFile()
{
     Timer timer = new .Timer(new TimerCallback(createtxtFile));
     timer.Change(0L, 5000);

     File.ReadLines(filePath).ToList().Take(1000)
                .AsParallel()
                .Select(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LiveAMData>>)
                .ForAll(WriteRecordTest);
}

static StreamWriter tempWriter;
static System.Threading.Tasks.Task t1;
public static async void WriteRecordTest(List<LiveAMData> data)
{
     List<LiveAMData> data1 = data.AsParallel().Where(x => symbolList.Contains(x.sym)).ToList();
     foreach (var dt in data1)
     {
          t1 = Task.Run(() =>
          {
              var result = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(((long)dt.s) * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);
              DateTime newDT = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(result, targetZone);
              lock(tempWriter)
              {
                  tempWriter.WriteLine(dt.sym + ", " + newDT.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss fff tt") + ", " + dt.v);
              }
          });
     }
}

public static void createtxtFile(object state)
{
    if(t1 != null)
    {
        Task.WhenAll(t1);
        sLogFname = $@"D:\LogFiles\{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.txt";
        tempWriter = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(sLogFname, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
    }
    else
    {
        sLogFname = $@"D:\LogFiles\{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.txt";
        tempWriter = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(sLogFname, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
    }
}
```

and in files last line becomes like it's stop mid of process and generate new file.

```
CORE, 05/02/2019 10:27:00 000 AM, 548
YUM, 05/02/2019 10:27:00 000 AM, 1109
DVY, 05/02/2019 10:27
```

Actually last record DVY is half data and this is happen in almost every files.

So I am thinking that this issue is happen due to second process (create file). So what solution I should apply for solve this issue?

Comment: You may have to make sure that your connections to the file are closed/disposed before you create a new connection to it.

Comment: @Symon I have make connection close for that file so it's giving error for "can not write in file due to connection is close". Also issue is continuous with connection close for files.

Comment: You will have to remake the connection in order to start writing to that file. Might be helpful to look into `using` statements. These will open and close/dispose the connection pretty seamlessly

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is a bad idea to use the tempwriter object as the lock object...

But, whats more important, you only lock your tempwriter in `WriteRecordTest`, so the lock has no use in `createtextfile`.

I think, as long as you are in your own piece of code, or even in the same class, you should be able to use a simple boolean variable to lock access to the file ressource

- check if the boolean is false, if not do nothing
- then set the boolean to true and do your work (on the one hand, write into the file, and on the other hand flush the file and reopen the next one)

With this hints, it should be possible to solve your problem...

[Edit on 2019-03-11:]

At first I thought, it would be easy to provide you with corrections to your code. But at a second look, I cant see what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Wolfgand Roth, Thank you for you suggestions. Is it means like set true or false on lock file and pass that boolean value for create file ? and also what should I replace with tempwriter ?

Comment: just use a `private static Boolean bLock;` and then query this variable and set it accordingly. (I will edit my answer to clarify).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am continuously receiving records from file and store it in text file. Also each text file generates on few seconds. So all these process run parallel and for that when new file generate on 5 second then records writer not completing it's operation. So last record becomes half. loss of data becomes in files.

Comment: I have set boolen value false by default and make it true when it goes to write in file and after write in file again I set it to false. All this actions I perform in WriteRecordTest and I check that boolean value into createTextFile. Like if boolean value is false then only create text file else it not generating file.
<br/> but also it's giving us same result. still last record becomes half. loss of data becomes in files.

Answer (score 0):

@Ankit, You dropped your code sample with details that are irrelevant to your question, making it more difficult to answer your question.  Your question, if I understand it correctly, is about the loss of data accuracy, which is more than likely, due to incorrect handling of threading, yet your code has serialization, logging and TimeZone complication in it.  The code WriteRecordTest(..) is decorated with async but no await can be found in it.  The code contains data types that are not provided and in order to answer your question we need to guess...

Taking off from the point of view that the code, as is, is difficult to reason about, I would like to propose restructuring of the code as follows:

1. Generate a producer (publisher) and consumer (subscriber) threads (known as pub-sub pattern):
2. The producer: read a controller file, `@"D:\TestSymbolsData.txt"`, line by line, in its own producer thread and accumulates the lines in a concurrent buffer, say `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, because these lines are ordered.
3. The consumer: a different thread will retrieve the lines off the buffer, the `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, and process the lines into a `tempWriter`.  Then every 5 seconds the `tempWriter` will be closed and a new one will be created/opened.  This 5 seconds interval need not be concurrent, before processing the next line retrieved from the buffer, you may check a timer if the timer is less than 5 seconds then proceed with the work of the consumer.  Otherwise, close the previous `tempWriter` and create a new one and proceed with BAU (business as usual).
4. You will need to be mindful of an empty buffer and having the consumer not crash but wait.  This will occur when the consumer processes the data in the buffer faster then the producer generates data into the buffer.
5. You will have to be mindful of a full buffer, and the producer will need to wait rather then crash.  This will occur when the producer generates data faster than the consumer processes it off the buffer.
6. You will need to have a trigger to signal and end the processes.